# SplitChunksPlugin not generating chunk for dependencies shared among entry points

Tags: webpack, splitchunksplugin

I'm trying to use code splitting so I can unit-test production code without duplicating modules. I would like webpack to recognize that my *.test.ts files rely on the same modules as the source code itself, and output a bundle containing those shared dependencies. However, webpack only outputs bundles corresponding to the entry points and does not extract the shared code into its own bundle.

I'm using the basic configuration provided in the official documentation for my use case (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting#prevent-duplication), but no luck. The only substantial difference I can see is that I'm using loaders to transpile my code, and the official examples aren't.

[git repo](https://gitlab.com/jlapointe/codesplittingtest)

Folder structure

```
|- /MyProject
  |- webpack.config.js
  |- /node_modules
  |- /build
  |- /src
    |- webServer.ts
    |- myLib.ts
    |- webServer.test.ts
    |- myLib.test.ts
```

webServer.ts

```
import './myLib';
// do webserver stuff
```

myLib.test.ts

```
import './myLib';
import mocha, chai, etc etc
// unit tests for myLib
```

webServer.test.ts

```
import './myLib.test';
// this file is just a convenient entry point for grouping unit tests
```

webpack.config.js

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const serverConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    webServer: './src/webServer.ts',
    'webServer.test': './src/webServer.test.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts']
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts/,
      include: [__dirname],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'babel-loader' },
        { loader: 'ts-loader' }
      ]
    }]
}
module.exports = [serverConfig];
```

I expect webpack to emit 3 files: `webServer.js`, `webServer.test.js`, and a third that bundles `myLib`. However, I only get 2 files: `webServer.js` and `webServer.test.js`

Comment: Can you upload the image of the build ? I want to see how webpack generate your bundle

Comment: Image of dependency tree: https://imgur.com/otHLKiR (the filenames are different. The shared dependency is called `auth-lib.ts`)

Comment: Can you share your code in github or something so i can take a look

Comment: Oh! Here: https://gitlab.com/jlapointe/codesplittingtest

Answer (score 4):

The following changes to my config fixed the problem for me.

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const serverConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    webServer: './src/webServer.ts',
    'webServer.test': './src/webServer.test.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts']
  },
  optimization: {
-   splitChunks: {
-     chunks: 'all',
-   }
+   splitChunks: {
+     cacheGroups: {
+       common: {
+         chunks: 'all',
+         enforce: true,
+         name: 'common'
+       }
+     }
+   }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts/,
      include: [__dirname],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'babel-loader' },
        { loader: 'ts-loader' }
      ]
    }]
}
module.exports = [serverConfig];
```